# I Don't Know What the Problem is with my AHK Script

Tags: arrays, syntax, autohotkey

I am working with a lot that I am unfamiliar with here so I can't find the problem even after looking through the documentation and trying fixes for roughly an hour.

The goal was to take screen coordinates and a hex color from a file one by one and check the screen to see if they match. If not then click at those coords. Originally I just repeatedly read the file with each iteration and it functioned, I think, except it produced an unusable amount of lag so I couldn't be sure. My troubles with that iteration and the code I ended up using are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181940/what-is-ahk-doing-here-and-what-did-i-get-wrong). Which is why now I'm moving on to creating a table in memory from the file at startup and using that instead. This is the file I'm using:

```
1123 680 0x201F42 
1178 679 0x0B3D55 
1232 679 0x12352D 
1286 680 0x0F211E 
1344 681 0x231D30 
1396 680 0x22171D 
1454 680 0x392E30
```

This is my code:

```
Loop, Read, % "out.txt"
{
    l := A_Index
    for k, v in StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, A_Space)
    {
        table[l,k] := v
    }
}

Loop
{
    if (GetKeyState("Space"))
    {
        for k, v in table
        {
            PixelGetColor, hue, % v[0], % v[1]
            if (hue != v[2])
            {
                Click, % v[0] ", " v[1]
            }
        }
    }
    Sleep, 20
}
```

And the only problem I can currently see is that nothing in the second `for` block is getting executed. I have tried finding my mistake(s) but so far I've been unsuccessful. Reading the documentation doesn't give me a clear answer or even point me in a helpful direction which is why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to create a [multidimensional array](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Arrays_of_Arrays), and it would work if you had first defined `table` to be an array or an object.
So for example just a simple `table := []` on top of your script would do it.
And then you'd end up with this:
[image: Variable Inspection]

You'll also notice how arrays in AHK are 1-based, as opposed to being 0-based like in many other languages.
Missed this when I fixed your other script earlier, so that'll need fixing as well.

Also, not sure if you knew, but [`PixelGetColor`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm) returns a color in BGR format. Not in RGB. So that also needs fixing, assuming it was a problem in the first place.
So assuming your color `0x201F42` was in RGB, it would be `0x421F20` in BGR.

And also, are you aware your coordinates are going to be relative to the active window?
If you don't want that, specify e.g [`CoordMode, Pixel, Screen`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) to make the coordinates relative to your whole screen.

---

So here's your script with `table := []` added in and indexing changed to 1-based.
Hopefully I didn't miss anything, I can't really test it.
Though, I'm guessing there's going to be some issues with the delays. No delay between clicks is probably not going to work. Try a `Sleep` under the `Click` command.
Also 20ms delay between the space bar checking loop is very short. Probably not going to yield good results.

```
table := []
Loop, Read, % "out.txt"
{
    l := A_Index
    for k, v in StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, A_Space)
    {
        table[l,k] := v
    }
}

Loop
{
    if (GetKeyState("Space"))
    {
        for k, v in table
        {
            PixelGetColor, hue, % v[1], % v[2]
            if (hue != v[3])
            {
                Click, % v[1] ", " v[2]
            }
        }
    }
    Sleep, 20
}
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I thought initializing the array was what I needed and I tried it at one point, but I tried `table := Object()` and `table := Array()`. When neither fixed it I suspected it was something else. Also yes I noted the color formatting. It's actually another script with pixelgetcolor that I'm using to generate the text file, so I figured keeping them both bgr would be one less step behind the scenes. And coordmode I forgot to account for but I'm familiar with it. Thank you once again for all your help. AHK oop is wonky to me!

Comment: Specifying `table := Object()` or `table := Array()` should be fine. Maybe your problem was just with the 0-based indexing.